# Рисовать символы рекурсией

Tags: javascript

```
function drStRec(str, n) {
if (n == 0) {
    return;
}
document.write(str);
drStRec(str, n - 1);
}

drStRec("*", 10);
```

Хочу добавить еще один параметр, скажем "m", чтоб при drStRec("*", 5, 10) получилось 5 строк с 10 звездами. Если можно, с объяснением, как это сделали, чтоб понимать..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

К сожалению, Вашу задачу решить невозможно. У Вас двойная рекурсия. И при выходе из одной, нужно знать, когда запустить вторую итерацию.

Выход - разбить функцию на две. Одна пусть рекурсивно печатает строки, а вторая - символы в этой строке

```js
function writeLine(str, m) {
  if (m != 0) {
    document.write(str);
    writeLine(str, m - 1);
  } else {
    document.write('<br/>');
  }
}

function drStRec(str, n, m) {
  if (n != 0) {
    writeLine(str, m);
    drStRec(str, n - 1, m);
  }
}

drStRec("*", 5, 10);
```

Еще один способ, передавать на всех уровнях рекурсии количество символов в строке. Тогда вторую итерацию можно начинать, передав это число

```js
function drStRec(str, n, m, curChar) {
  // Если номер текущего символа не переедан, то устанавливаем его в общее число символов
  if (curChar === undefined)
    curChar = m;
  if (curChar != 0) {
    document.write(str);
    drStRec(str, n, m, curChar - 1);
  } else {
    document.write('<br/>');
    if (n != 0)
      drStRec(str, n - 1, m);
  }
}

drStRec("*", 5, 10);
```

Comment: Здорово! Особенно с двумя функциями! )))

Answer (score 2):

```js
function drStRec(str, n, m) {
  if (n != 0) { //если n не равно 0 то выполнить вывод и вызвать функцию с n - 1
    var res = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) { //Цикл который создает строку с m звездами
      res += str;
    }
    document.write(res + "<br>");
    drStRec(str, n - 1, m);
  }
}

drStRec("*", 5, 10);
```

Comment: показывает просто 21....

Comment: function drawStarsWithLoop(str, m, n) {
    var res = "";
    for (var i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        res += "<br />";
        for (var j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            res += str;
        }
    }
    return res;
}        
document.write(drawStarsWithLoop("*", 4, 20)); Циклами я так сделал, но меня интересует чисто рекурсивное решение...

Comment: Я дал рабочую рекурсивную функцию которая выполняет свою работу, следуя описанию вопроса (который в принципе и не вопрос даже)
p.s. рекурсия это когда функция вызывает сама себя же. Но это не значит что она должна что то возвращать

Comment: Ok Bogdan Bida, спасибо.